# How to connect a widget with pointerMoved event function in XAML?

Tags: xaml, windows-8

In MAXL, I can implement like this to add a pointermoved event for a TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="Drag and Drop" 
AllowDrop="True" 
PointerMoved="TextBlock_PointerMoved"
/>
```

Then I just need to implement the function to finish the work of pointermoved:

```
TextBlock_PointerMoved(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::PointerRoutedEventArgs^ e);
```

But Now, I need to do this in code area using C++, I will new a textblock, and create everything in code. For example:

```
TextBlock^ my_textblock = ref new TextBlock();
my_textblock->SetValue(TextBlock::TextProperty, "My Text Block");
my_textblock->SetValue(TextBlock::WidthProperty, 100);
```

What should I do to connect the pointermoved event function with the widget? Hopefully like this:

```
my_textblock->SetValue(TextBlock::PointerMovedEvent, myPointerMovedFunction);
```

but it does not work. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the method like this:

```
panelitem->PointerMoved += ref new PointerEventHandler(this, &MainPage::StackPanel_PointerMoved_A);
```

`StackPanel_PointerMoved_A` is your PointerEventHandler function.